# opening an exml file and importing to datagridview

Tags: xml, vb.net, excel

I am attempting to open an xml file using ACE OLEDB but I am getting the error of the excel database being read-only. I can assure you, I have full permissions to this xml file.

Using the following code, I am receiving the read-only error:

```
Using MyConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=H:\Import\SER 2901 Fellow Cmts 063015B.xml;" + "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
    Using MyCommand = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [SER export$]", MyConnection)
        Dim ds = New System.Data.DataSet
        MyCommand.Fill(ds) 
    End Using
End Using
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I simply want to get this information into my datagridview.

Comment: I dont think you are supposed to specify the file in the connection string.  Just the path.  The file is picked up from the SQL SELECT statement.  At least with .xls files, that is so; I am not sure OleDB would work differently with xml types

Comment: Are you suggesting i remove .xml from the connection string? If i do that, what do i change in my select statement? I just tried removing .xml and i ended up with a new error of: Cannot find object SER export$

Comment: Do you have the file open in Excel? It can't be open in Excel when try to open a connection to it.

Comment: @TyCobb, no sir. It is closed.

Comment: Nevermind, leave it there.  I was thinking if something else.

Comment: It's worth noting, i did quite a bit of "Google Research" and found empty solutions for this exact problem.

Comment: try adding `Mode=ReadWrite` to the connection string: `"...Mode=ReadWrite;Extended Properties=..."`  you dont need that concatenation, and your DataSet will only exist inside those Using blocks

Comment: @Plutonix: i tried changing my connections string to: Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=C:\FileName.xml;Mode=ReadWrite;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0; - but i am still receiving the read-only error.

Comment: You peaked my interest as I assumed by your use of Excel 8.0, that you were attempting to open an "2003 xml spreadsheet" and I've never seen that done.  After several failed attempts and a web search I've come to the conclusion that that can not be done.  Then it occurred to me that you possibly have a typo and that the file extension should be "xlsm".  If you specify a file that does not exist, you will get that "read-only" error.  If you really meant an xlsm file, then you should be using the Extended property "Excel 12.0" and not "Excel 8.0".